# Is there a way to get YTPlayerView to play full screen on an iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad, youtube-api

In `loadWithVideoId:playerVars:` I'm setting `playsinline` to `@0`.

I'm also calling `ytPlayer.webView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = NO;`.

The video plays full screen on iPhone, but plays inside the web view on the iPad.

How can I get full screen playback on both iPhone and iPad?

Answer (score -2):

Find the YTPlayerView-iframe-player.html file and add the following css style.

```
<style>
    body { margin: 0; width:100%%; height:100%%; }

    html { width:100%%; height:100%%; }
</style>
```

I see YTPlayerView play in fullscreen on iPhone and iPad both.

Comment: This is already in the HTML on the tip of the helper library from Youtube.  This did not solve the issue for me.  Do you have a sample project set up with this working?  I'd love to see it.

Comment: Yes, please check [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/frg024mfwqwxewu/MyYoutubeTest1.zip?dl=0).

Comment: This is not the solution I'm looking for.  You are playing the video *inline*, but making the view full screen.  You are not having it automatically start in true full screen model.  In other words, it's still in the web view.

Comment: So `allowsInlineMediaPlayback = NO` is a must in the solution?

Comment: The question asks for a solution that doesn't play inline by default.  I've done some extensive testing on this and was unable to get it to work on iPad.  It seems iPad requires web view video playback to be inline regardless of the `allowsInlineMediaPlayback` flag